# CORS error after setting origin in Koa server

Tags: javascript, node.js, cors, koa

I have set up my server as below, specifying the origin as the netlify adddress of our react app. but we still get cors errors. Access to fetch at 'https://lendify-production.up.railway.app/collection/all' from origin 'https://grand-tapioca-07d51d.netlify.app' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

```
    import Koa from 'koa';
    import parser from 'koa-bodyparser';
    import cors from 'koa-cors';
    import proxy from 'koa-proxies';
    import { Server } from 'socket.io';
    import http from 'http';
    import dotenv from 'dotenv';
    import router from './router';
    import connectDb from './models/_index';
    import { ioConnect } from './controllers/socketHandler.controller';

    dotenv.config();
    const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5001;
    const app = new Koa();

    app.use(cors({
      origin: process.env.CLIENT_URL,
      methods: ['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE', 'OPTIONS'],
      headers: ['Origin', 'Content-Type', 'Accept', 'Authorization'],
      credentials: true,
    }));
    
    
    app.use(parser());
    app.use(router.routes());
    app.use(router.allowedMethods());
```

We are able to login but with every other route i get a cors error. I have taken out the authentication and  I have tried setting up a proxy but plays havoc with the socket.io we have set up. the headers are somehow not set up correctly with the cors.

Comment: Can you check in the browser network devtools tab and check the preflight request and check if there is the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header. If it exist check if the url is same with this page url even http and https is different url.

Comment: What is the value of `process.env.CLIENT_URL`? Is it a valid [Web-origin value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Origin)?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header on your server to the same value as the Origin from which the request originates. This way, when the browser executes the preflight request, your server will return this header in the response, allowing your Origin to access the requested resource.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

If you call an API from one origin to different origin, the browsers bloack them. You need to allow Cross Origin access for specific origin like shown below

```js
app.use(cors({
  origin: ['https://google.com/','https://facebook.com','http://localhost:3000']
}));
```

or allow all origins like

```js
app.use(cors({
  origin: "*"
}));
```

Comment: `https://google.com/`? Did you mean `https://google.com` (no trailing slash) instead?

Comment: Also, the purpose of CORS isn't to block cross-origin requests, and the Same-Origin Policy doesn't block _all_ cross-origin requests. For example, try it yourself by opening the DevTools and running `fetch('//example.com', {mode: 'no-cors'})`. The browser will block the client from accessing the response, but it _will_ send the request.